# How to draw a dotted line and box for each trade

Tags: pine-script

I have a strategy sript with strategy entry and close, but I struggle to draw a line between entry and close for every trade. Could You helkp me what am I doing wrong please?

```
//@version=5
strategy("Linia transakcji", "JJJ", overlay=true)
var float entryPrice = na
var float exitPrice = na
enterTrade = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 50), ta.open)
if enterTrade
    entryPrice := close
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
exitTrade = close >= entryPrice + 100 * syminfo.mintick
if exitTrade
    exitPrice := close
    strategy.close("Long")

// Rysowanie linii transakcji
if not na(entryPrice) and not na(exitPrice)
    line.new(x1 = bar_index[1], y1 = entryPrice, x2 = bar_index, y2 = exitPrice, color = color.blue, width = 2)
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code?

Comment: When do you want to draw the line? When you enter a trade or when you exit a trade?

Answer (score 0):

You must clarify what are you facing exactly, elaborate more

You're setting the exitPrice only when the exit condition is met but you're not resetting it after drawing the line. Same goes for entryPrice. This might cause issue.
Since the line.new function is outside of any conditional statement, it will be executed on every bar when both entryPrice and exitPrice are not na. This is not ideal. You should ensure that the line is only drawn when there's a new exit, and after drawing the line, reset both entryPrice and exitPrice to na.

Try this:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Linia transakcji", "JJJ", overlay=true)

var float entryPrice = na
var float exitPrice = na

enterTrade = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 50), ta.open)
if enterTrade
    entryPrice := close
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

exitTrade = close >= entryPrice + 100 * syminfo.mintick
if exitTrade
    exitPrice := close
    strategy.close("Long")

// Rysowanie linii transakcji
if not na(entryPrice) and not na(exitPrice)
    line.new(x1 = bar_index[1], y1 = entryPrice, x2 = bar_index, y2 = exitPrice, color = color.blue, width = 2)
    entryPrice := na
    exitPrice := na
```